# Volume of the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ when it's rotated about the line $x=1$

Tags: integration, volume

I have to find the volume of the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ when it's rotated about the line $x=1$.

Since $y=x^2\Leftrightarrow x=\sqrt{y}$ and $y=x^2\Leftrightarrow x=\sqrt[3]{y}$, so the outer radius would be
$$1-\sqrt{y}$$
while the inner radius is equal to
$$1-\sqrt[3]{y}$$
Hence, the volume is given by
$$\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left((1-\sqrt{y})^{2}-(1-\sqrt[3]{y})^{2}\right)dy$$
I just want to know if it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is. But https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: I agree, it appears correct.

Comment: That policy is intended to avoid users posting long solutions and expecting readers to parse through the whole thing to find an error or errors that may not even exist. I don't believe that situation exists here, since the posting is short, clearly written, and focuses only on the set-up of the integral. In other words, if the OP had posted the entire solution all the way through the evaluation of the integral, and then asked us to check the set-up of the integral, I believe it would have (rightly) passed muster without much comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Plot of x squared and x cubed]

This plot confirms, that when rotating around the line x=1, the outer radius comes from $y=x^2$ and the inner radius comes from $y=x^3$.  This makes the outer radius $1-y^{\frac12}$ and the inner radius $1-y^{\frac13}$. Also, that this area is closed, this is the only close area bounded by these two y's, and the points of intersection.

Note: Technically, only algebra can conclusively demonstrate these facts, the intersection points, etc., and the graphs merely but strongly suggests these facts.

Comment: oops, you're right, I phrased it wrong and fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

One can do without sowtfare plots or algebraically in the following way:
$$1-\sqrt y\stackrel{?}{>}1-\sqrt[3]y$$
$$\sqrt[3]y\stackrel{?}{>}\sqrt y$$
Taking sixth power
$$y^2\stackrel{?}{>}y^3$$
$$1>y$$
It checks since $y\in (0,1)$.